# How to export mongoDB data into a CSV format?

Tags: excel, mongodb, csv

I'm looking for a very simple way to export data from mongoDB into a CSV. Most of the answers involve bash scripts… etc.  Is there a simple mongoDB command that will just export the data into CSV?

Comment: Have you tried using [`mongoexport --csv`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)?

Comment: just that?  i'm in mongo and i get syntax error, 'unexpected identifier'.

Comment: It's a shell command, so you just need to be in bash or whatever shell you are using.

Comment: Thanks for responses, but still having trouble.  is there a simple example you can point to?

Comment: Have a look at these [**examples**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#usage) and see if they help.

Comment: Thanks very much! That looks helpful.  last question: are those commands for the regular shell?  or, are those for use 'in' mongo?

Comment: Yes these are for the regular shell. These are better described as _utility functions_ and ship with the mongoDB download (for example on windows you get a `monogoexport.exe` file). The `in` mongoDB commands are different and called the [`mongo Shell Mehods`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update:**

As of mongo 3.0.6 `--csv` is no longer supported and the new flag is `--type=csv`, so the command would be

`mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --type=csv --fieldFile fields.txt`

**Original answer:**

This can be done from the command line using the mongo *utility function* [`mongoexport --csv`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/).

Alongside the `--csv` the documentation states that you also need to use [`--fields`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--fields) or specify a file with the fields in using [`--fieldFile`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--fieldFile).

Have a look at the [**usage examples**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#usage) and see if they help, for example:

```
mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --csv --fieldFile fields.txt
```

Comment: csv flag is deprecated; please use --type=csv instead

Answer (score 7):

If you already have the .bson file, in order to export to csv:

```
bsondump collection.bson > file.csv
```

Comment: This exports raw json objects line by line, not valid table

Answer (score 2):

Although, the above answers are correct, but it won't work until you add the `--out` parameter where you specify your csv file.

The command would be:

`mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --type=csv --fieldFile fields.txt --out=contacts_output.csv`

where,

`--out=<output_file_name>`
or
`-o=<output_file_name>` should be used to specify the output file that you want to export to.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy with mongoDB compass, you just need to goto

`Collection -> Export Collection -> Select Export data as JSON or CSV`

and export the data.